# Swift: How to show DFPBannerView full width of Screen device?

Tags: swift, google-dfp

I have an Application, I'm using Swift language for my app.
In App, I used DFPBannerView to show Ads.

My source code:
--------- **Solution 1:**

```
private func getBannerView() -> DFPBannerView{
        // return DFP's banner view.
        var bannerView: DFPBannerView = DFPBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height, kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height));
        bannerView.adUnitID = "/48012543/NIFTY_SPAPP/TRAFFIC_NEKO/IOS/ABNR"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self

        var request:DFPRequest = DFPRequest()

        bannerView.loadRequest(request)

        return bannerView

    }
```

---

If I run App on iphone 5s then DFPBanner is displayed full width screen device. But when I run app on Iphone 6 then DFP is displayed not full width screen device.
In order to fix this problem, I change code:
--------- **Solution 2:**

```
private func getBannerView() -> DFPBannerView{
        // return DFP's banner view.
        var bannerView: DFPBannerView = DFPBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height));
        bannerView.adUnitID = "/48012543/NIFTY_SPAPP/TRAFFIC_NEKO/IOS/ABNR"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.tag = 1012

        var request:DFPRequest = DFPRequest()

        bannerView.loadRequest(request)

        return bannerView

    }
```

---

If i'm use code in Solution 2 then DFPBannerView not show on Iphone 6 (on Iphone 5s: DFPBannerView show normal).

How to show DFPBannerView full width of Screen device (iphone 6)?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to fix my problem.

I don't use **kGADAdSizeBanner** for DFPBanner, I change to **kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait**.

My source code get DFPBanner:

```
private func getBannerView() -> DFPBannerView{
        // return DFP's banner view.
        var bannerView: DFPBannerView = DFPBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        bannerView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50)
        bannerView.adUnitID = "/48012543/NIFTY_SPAPP/TRAFFIC_NEKO/IOS/ABNR"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.tag = 1012

        var request:DFPRequest = DFPRequest()

        bannerView.loadRequest(request)

        return bannerView

    }
```